# what is the best way to parse this string in java?

Tags: java, parsing

what is the best way to parse this string in java ?

```
Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Local Area Connection

Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Local Area Connection 2
```

between each word is space, not tab, not any thing else, as you can see number of space is not equal, and also between the word such as "local area connection" is space.

actually i want the name of all of my network interface and the state of them.
this is the output of "netsh" command in windows. (if you know other command witch can get me this info as key:value, it will be helpfull. or may be there is a argument for this command to format it?)

if i can get something like this it will help alot :

**Interface Name : Local Area Connection

Type : Dedicated

State : Connected

Admin State : Enabled**

**Interface Name : Local Area Connection 2

Type : Dedicated

State : Connected

Admin State : Enabled**

Comment: Looks like the pattern is not weird enough to use regex, try to write something to separate the columns and just give a special attention to the first row (columns headers). Do you want the actual code? did you try peoplePerHour.com?

Comment: @TomCammann  i tried something with String.split(), but i can not get the desired result.

Comment: @nickecarlo  : thanks man, i didn't even think about that, you are the great help.

Comment: @theMarceloR  : thanks, the hint may be usefull, i will try that

Comment: code tested and works - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(myString));

String line;
while (!(line = b.readLine()).startsWith("-----")) {/*skip*/};

while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.trim().equals("")) continue; // skip blank lines
    String[] splat = line.split(" +",4);
    System.out.println("Interface Name : " + splat[3]);
    System.out.println("Type : " + splat[2]);
    System.out.println("State : " + splat[1]);
    System.out.println("Admin State : " + splat[0]);
}
b.close();
```

Comment: Shouldn't the regex be `" +"` instead of `" *"`?

Comment: Maybe two spaces would be better... (Sorry, I can't put it here, the code formatter shows only one: `"  +"`)

Answer (score 2):

You should use Java capabilities to get the network interfaces. The class [`NetworkInterface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) provides what you are looking for.

You can find an example here: [Listing Network Interface Addresses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html)

Comment: To me this sounds like a better solution to the OP's real problem.  Unfortunately, that's a whole different question than the one he actually asked.  :P

Comment: @cHao yes... but I would say the OP asks the wrong question ;-)

Comment: this seems the better way after all, but in the link you mentioned, the code just find the name of network interface, not the state of it, i will explore the class, may be there is some method to do this.

Comment: +1 I like your answer a lot better than mine.  And @cHao see also [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891/155831)  My take on it is 'hell yes!'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I tend to agree.  I have several "don't do it" answers.  :)  But there's a decently generic fixed-width-table-parsing question lurking in the OP somewhere, and someone opening a question entitled "what is the best way to parse this..." is probably looking for a way to parse stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If the columns are of known width, use `String.substring(..)` to get each column & `trim()` the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the positions, you can do like

```
String state = line.substring(15, 30).trim();
```

If you don't know, then parse the first line for the known headers (like `line.indexOf("State")`), that will tell you the positions.

```
// for the header line
int stateBegin = line.indexOf("State");
int typeBegin = line.indexOf("Type");

// for all other lines
String state = line.substring(stateBegin, typeBegin).trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's no column separator:

1 - It seems to be fixed size fields. This means the columns will always have X caracters, and next column will always start at X+1. In your exemple, "Admin State" will always have 15 characters and "State" will always begin on 16th character. "State" has also 15 characters [...]

2 - If fixed size fields don't work, you can try to parse by 2 spaces, but its way prone to errors

Answer (score 0):

```
String s ="Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name";
String[] str = s.split("  +");
for(String ss: str)
    System.out.println(ss);
```

Try above code to split String with more than one space.

Output:

```
Admin State
State
Type
Interface Name
```